# Not getting array back from $youtube_array instead giving object(stdClass)#1

Tags: php, arrays, api

I am trying to request a youtube array, but the var dump reveals a dump starting with object(stdClass)#1

```
<?php
$num = Rand(1,5);
switch ($num) {
case 1: header('Foo Fighters The Pretender'); $music= 'Foo Fighters The Pretender';
case 2: header('Arctic Monkeys Flourescent Adolescent'); $music= 'Arctic Monkeys Flourescent Adolescent';
case 3: header('The Strokes Under Cover of Darkness'); $music= 'under cover of darkness';
case 4: header('The White Stripes Seven Nation Army'); $music= 'the white stripes seven nation army';
case 5: header('Franz Ferdinand Michael'); $music= 'franz ferdinand michael';
}
$youtube_array = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?alt=json&q=" . urlencode($music) , TRUE ));
var_dump($youtube_array);
echo "<h1>Your Song Is:</h1>";
echo $music;
echo "</p>";
echo "YouTube found this video about your Rock:";
echo "</p>";
$link = $youtube_array['feed']['entry'][0]['id']['$t'];
$link2 = substr($link, 42);
echo "<iframe width='960' height='720' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/" . $link2 . "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've misplaced the right parenthesis in this line:

```
$youtube_array = json_decode(file_get_contents("-" . urlencode($music) , TRUE ));
```

should be

```
$youtube_array = json_decode(file_get_contents("-" . urlencode($music)), TRUE );
```

Answer (score 0):

[json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) has a second parameter ([, bool $assoc = false ....). If it is left at the default, it will return an object. With it true, it sets an associative array.

Your code has the 'true' in with the '`file_get_contents($filename [, bool $use_include_path...`'